# CSS inline style selector not working for iOS (safari, chrome)

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, safari, less

I have something like this:

HTML:

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;">

<div class="test"></div>

</body>
```

CSS/LESS:

```
body[style*="overflow: hidden"] {
.test {z-index: 1;}
}
```

When body has inline style overflow: hidden I'm trying to give some style to the test div. This is working in all browsers, all android devices but on iOS (iphone x, 8 ect.) it's not working. It does not matter safari or chrome on iOS is not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't believe that your code as shown above works in _any_ browser. That is not valid CSS. Are you using a preprocessor?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it's in LESS.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to match exactly. Try it without the asterix (*).

```
body[style="overflow: hidden;"] {
    .test {z-index: 1;}
}
```

The style needs to be an exact match.

However, I would advise you to use classes for this, the above code is very ugly.

Try this:

HTML

```
<body class="overflow-hidden">
    <div class="test"></div>  
</body>
```

CSS

```
.overflow-hidden .test {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

LESS/SASS

```
.overflow-hidden {
    .test {
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that about classes but unfortunately I need it like this. I will try without asterix (*).